# Como regreso al inicio de una función con un parámetro?

Tags: python, funciones

Estoy intentando realizar un programa de cifrado, y lo único que me falta es que después de que el n sea mayor a 2 y se rompa el while, el contador vuelva a 0, se le sumen 2, para ir con el siguiente conjunto de letras, y volver a repetir el while. Para retornar al inicio de una función normalmente uso return Funcion(), pero como hago para retornar si tiene un parametro como esta CifradoCodTel(palabra)????

```
import string
letras=list(string.ascii_uppercase)
numeros=['21','22','23','31','32','33','41','42','43','51','52','53','61','62','63','71','72','73','74','81','82','83','91','92','93','94']

def CifradoCodTel(palabra):
    palabracifrada="  "
    n=0
    while n<3:
        list(palabra)
        nletra=(palabra[n]+palabra[n+1])
        if nletra in numeros:
            nnumero=numeros.index(nletra)
            palabracifrada=palabracifrada+letras[nnumero]
            n=n+2
        else:
            palabracifrada=palabracifrada+" "
            n=n+1
    if n>3:
       n=0
       n=n+2
       return CifradoCodTel()
            
    return palabracifrada
            

n=str(input("palabra que desea: "))
print(CifradoCodTel(n))
```

Comment: supongo que eso lo quieres hacer si `n` es mayor a 3, verdad???

Comment: exactamente....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

para volver al inicio de un ciclo o loop, se emplea la sentencia, exclusiva de los loops, `continue`, esta sentencia sirve para volver al inicio del bucle, si quieres *resetear* las variables, es correcto la forma en que lo haces.

```py
def CifradoCodTel(palabra):
    palabracifrada="  "
    n=0
    while n<3:
        ...
        if n>3:
            n = 0
            # n=n+2 #no se para que quieres esto
            continue #volvemos al inicio
```

También lo podrías hacer haciendo un llamado nuevamente a la función, pero eso sería usar recursividad y recordemos que la recursividad nunca es buena :)